# Event delegation detecting outside clicks in (pure) JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

Essentially, what I want to do is place an event listener on a list of dynamically generated elements. When clicking on those elements, the element changes to the `<input>` tag so the user may alter it. Clicking outside of that element would change the `<input>` tag back to the original `<div>` tag. Since only one element would have an input tag at a time, I just used `querySelector("input")` to search for the element, and detected if the click happened on that `<input>` element. If it did not, switch it back to `<div>`

My issue is that it's to my understanding that checking for clicks outside of an element, it would require a listener on the entire document, but when I checked for inside clicks, I used event delegation. However, with two separate listeners, it seems that one automatically undoes the other. Immediately after clicking on an element within the list, the the `<input>` tag switches back to `<div>` because the click happened when the element was a `<div>` thereby not allowing any user alteration.

How can I fix this issue? I was thinking that two separate event listeners wouldn't work, but I can't have one event listener both listen onto the entire document, and the list I apply event delegation onto.

I am fairly new to Javascript, so I would greatly appreciate any answers or corrections to my methodology. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) or [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), and [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

Comment: It may help to [show your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and let us know what specifically goes wrong.